# Backpropagation in python: cannot understand a line of code

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network, deep-learning, backpropagation

I am trying to read the following code for back propagation in python

```
probs = exp_scores /np.sum(exp_scores, axis=1, keepdims=True) 
#Backpropagation
delta3 = probs
delta3[range(num_examples), y] -= 1
dW2 = (a1.T).dot(delta3)
....
```

but I cannot understand the following line of the code:

```
delta3[range(num_examples), y] -= 1
```

could you please tell me what does this do?

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things here. First it is using numpy slicing to select only a fraction of `delta3`. Secondly it is removing 1 to every element of this fraction of the matrix.

More precisely, `delta3[range(num_example), y]` is selecting lines of the matrix `delta3` ranging from 0 to `num_examples` but only selecting column `y`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're interested, *why* it's computed this way, it's the backpropagation through cross-entropy loss:

- `probs` is the vector of class probabilities (computed in a forward pass via softmax).
- `delta3` is the error signal from the loss function.
- `y` holds the ground truth classes for the mini-batch.

Everything else is just a math, which is well explained in [this post](https://deepnotes.io/softmax-crossentropy) and they end up with the same numpy expression.